# What local actions should be done after changing author info on GitHub?

Tags: git, rebase

I wanted to remove personal email addresses from commits to a GitHub repo, so I followed the Git Bash [steps they provide](https://help.github.com/en/articles/changing-author-info), which update the affected commits using `git filter-branch` in a temp clone repo, and end by running this:

```
git push --force --tags origin 'refs/heads/*'
```

The repo looks correct on GitHub now, with cleaned-up emails. However, I'm new to Git, and unsure what follow-up I need to do to sync up my local copy.

When I try to pull, I get the error "refusing to merge unrelated histories".

I had no changes locally before this, so maybe the simplest thing would be to just delete my local repo and check out the project again, but that's not the best practice or most flexible way to go as I understand it.

It seemed like I needed to rebase against that rewritten history, maybe like this:

```
git pull --rebase
```

Is that the best approach? If not, what is?

SIDE NOTE: I'm working in IntelliJ IDEA, ideally using the cmd line only for unusual things like that author-change script, and its Pull dialog doesn't have a Rebase option, but Update Project does, so that's what I actually did. Was that right?

Answer (score 2):

When you rewrite history like this, you can—and your case did—get what amounts to a *new and different repository*.  In this case *all existing clones of the old repository are only of any use with the old repository*.  You now simply make new clones of the new repository, which is a new project that you should never connect to the old project: the two are no longer compatible and commits can no longer be transferred from one to the other.

This is a simplified view of the complicated reality, but it should suffice for your case.  If you want to understand the reality, read on.

#### Git mostly cares about commits, but what exactly is a commit?

The essence of a Git repository is a pair of databases.  The big database is the one that holds all the commits, or more precisely, all the Git objects.  (There are four types of Git objects: commit, tree, blob, and annotated tag.  Trees and blobs are how commits store files within themselves, while annotated tag objects are just to hold annotated tag data.)  Every unique Git object has a unique hash ID, so every commit has its own unique hash ID, different from every other commit.

Not only are all these hash IDs unique, they're also *universal*.  (They are [Globally Universal IDs or GUIDs, also called UUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).)  This means that every Git everywhere in the universe uses the *same* GUID for that commit.

The way Git actually achieves this is that the ID is a cryptographic checksum of the *content* of the commit.  This means it's literally impossible to change *anything* in a commit: if you actually manage to change something, what you get is a new and different commit, with a new and different hash ID.  Given the hash ID, Git can check to see if it has the object.  If so, it can retrieve the object.  If not, your Git can ask some other Git (that does have the object) for the full object, and stuff the resulting object into its big database.

Whenever we have the hash ID and the actual object is in the database, we say that we have a *pointer to* the object.  These pointers let us find the commits (or other Git objects, but mostly we work with commits).

In any case, the actual contents of a commit are usually pretty short: each commit holds the hash ID of the snapshot of the files for that commit—that's the data you want to keep forever—plus a set of *metadata* such as your name and email address.  One of the pieces of metadata for each commit, though, is the commit's *parent* hash ID (or IDs plural, if the commit is a merge commit).  So each commit points to its parent, by hash ID.

We can draw this, and if we use single uppercase letters to stand in for commits, it even looks kind of reasonable.  (Of course we'll run out of letters quickly, which is why Git uses those big ugly hash IDs.)  Here's an example of a repository with just a `master` and eight commits whose hash IDs are `A` through `H`:

```
A <-B <-C ... <-F <-G <-H   <--master
```

The *last* commit on the branch named `master` has hash ID `H`.  Commit `H` itself stores the hash ID of commit `G`, which stores the ID of `F`, and so on.  Eventually we work all the way back to the very first commit ever, commit `A`.  It has *no* parent, because it can't have one: it was the first commit.  That lets us (and Git) stop.

Note that Git has to work *backwards* all the time.  We always start at the end—the *tip commit* of some branch—as found by some branch name.  Hence, Git's second smaller database is a table of names—branch names, tag names, and other *references*—each of which holds exactly one hash ID.  When the reference is a branch name, the hash ID is that of a commit, and by following all the backwards-pointing arrows, we find all the commits that are *reachable from* the branch.

When we make a new branch, we just make a new *name* that points to some existing commit:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, develop
```

Now *both* branches point to commit `H`.  We pick one branch to be "on" and use `git checkout` to attach our `HEAD` to the branch:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, develop (HEAD)
```

Now we can make a new commit, in the usual way.  When we do, Git packages up all our files, attaches our metadata—our log message, name, email address, the time stamp, and so on—and writes out a new commit.  The parent of the new commit is the current commit `H`.  The new commit's data hashes to some big ugly random-looking string that is different from every other commit ever, but we'll just call `I`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, develop (HEAD)
            \
             I
```

and now the really clever bit happens.  Now Git writes `I`'s hash ID into whichever branch name `HEAD` is attached to:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

If we switch back to `master` and make new commits there, the two branches diverge.

#### filter-branch copies commits

What `git filter-branch` does is to list out every commit—or every commit from some subset, depending on your options—and start extracting each one, running the filters you specify—plus one more, though you can specify that one too—and making new commits from the result.  Whenever a filter *changes* anything, by definition, the new commit won't be bit-for-bit identical to the old one, so it will get a different hash ID.<sup>1</sup>  The extra filter is the one that makes the new commits, and it automatically swaps out the parent hash ID for the result from making any earlier changes.  So suppose you have:

```
        D--E   <-- master
       /
A--B--C
       \
        F--G  <-- feature
```

and your filter changes your author information.  Commit `A` becomes new commit `A'`:

```
        D--E   <-- master
       /
A--B--C
       \
        F--G  <-- feature

A'   [in progress]
```

Now filter-branch has to copy `B`.  Even if your filter makes *no* change, the new commit must have `A'` as its parent, not `A`, so the final commit-maker changes the parent hash (and perhaps an earlier filter changes the author information too) and we get:

```
        D--E   <-- master
       /
A--B--C
       \
        F--G  <-- feature

A'-B'   [in progress]
```

This repeats all the way out to both `E` and `G`:

```
        D--E   <-- master
       /
A--B--C
       \
        F--G  <-- feature

        D'-E'  <-- (replacement for master)
       /
A'-B'-C'
       \
        F'-G'  <-- (replacement for feature)
```

Once `git filter-branch` has made its pass over every commit, it does the name replacements: it stuffs `E'`'s ID into `master` and `G'`'s ID into `feature`, and now your names database no longer remembers the original `E` and `G` at all, and everything you look at will start from `E'` or `G'`.  These new and (really or at least supposedly) improved commits are the ones you want; you *want* to forget the old ones.

The old commits *are* still in there—and in fact filter-branch copies the original `master` reference to `refs/original/refs/heads/master`, for instance—but the new set of commits is the new repository.  Cloning this repository will *not* copy the originals, only the reachable new-and-improved commits.  Removing the `refs/original/` names will make Git garbage-collect the old commits, eventually (typically some time after 30 days, though exactly how long after, depends on a lot of other factors).

---

<sup>1</sup>If the filters make literally *no* change, the new commit *is* bit-for-bit identical to the original, and therefore has the original commit's hash ID and literally *is* the original commit.  But the last filter, the one that makes the commit itself, will often change something.

Comment: Thanks for your very informative post @torek, helps solidify my understanding. I don't get this though: "You now simply make new clones of the new repository, which is a new project that you should never connect to the old project: the two are no longer compatible and commits can no longer be transferred from one to the other." That's not what GitHub recommends, or what I did, at least literally. GitHub's process force pushes the temp repo, overwriting the original, and locally, it's the same project. The original commits are gone, new work is based on the new versions, but it's the same repo.

Comment: @enigment: I have here my grandfather's axe. It's just two parts, an iron chopping head and a wooden handle. My father replaced the handle when it broke, and I replaced the head last year. No parts of my grandfather's axe remain. Is this axe really my grandfather's axe? Answer that question and you have the answer to whether a repository in which all parts have been replaced is the  same repository as the one before replacing all the parts. More generally, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus

Comment: Like the Ship, a repository can be partially or mostly replaced. The interesting part that happens with Git, though, is that Git is greedy for new commits. Suppose you've taken the Ship of Theseus and replaced about half of it, and used the half from the old one to build a replica. Do you now have two ships, both of which are the Ship of Theseus? If they were Git and you placed them next to each other, they would fuse and become a much larger ship.

Comment: I get what you're saying about having replaced every commit, but practically speaking, and rotted ships aside, my literalist Git-newb brain was just trying to make sure about what I needed to actually do. Am I right that `git pull --rebase` (update all the parts) is just as valid as trashing my local repo and checking it out again (new local repo)?

Comment: Well, here's where the analogy falls apart. You've done this filter-branch and copied all your commits to new ones that otherwise *look* the same, except for the new author information and hash IDs. If you direct an *old* Git repository to *combine* the old and new commits, you end up with *both sets of commits*, now conjoined by some extra linkage. That's what happens if you do a merge. If you do a rebase ... well, rebase works by *copying* commits, then replacing the old ones with the new and improved copies. What happens if you copy the wrong-author commits atop the right-author ones?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the process that you'll choose to get your local repo in sync, the end result is the same : both repos with the same history. In this case, the local being overwritten by the remote version.

So, as you don't have local changes to keep, **most probably nothing will be cleaner and quicker than cloning the project again as you considered**. I'd say go for it.

*(As a sidenote, I don't see any reason why this would be a bad practice. What specific problem do you foresee?)*

Comment: Just that you wouldn't want to do that if you have local changes.